# ProgressBar - Not Updating AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I recently posted this question and tried to have it resolved but I implemented a few changes which didn't work. (progress bar is spinning circle forever)

The below code will be commented to show the issue. There is no error thrown and it just doesn't seem to work. Progressbar implemented and passed to a AsyncTask which uses publishProgress and passes it to OnProgressUpdated() which tries to update progress (progressbar).

Thank you all.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (!(data.get(position) instanceof TemporarySongInfomation)) {
        SongViewHolder holder;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list_format, null);
        holder = new SongViewHolder();
        holder.timesplayed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        holder.artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        holder.imagebutton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        holder.source = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        tempValue = (SongInfomation) data.get(position);
        String songName = tempValue.getName();
        holder.imagebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbutton1);
        holder.source.setText(tempValue.getVideoid());
        holder.title.setText(songName.length() > 45 ? songName.substring(0, 38) + "..." : songName);
        holder.timesplayed.setText("" + tempValue.getTimesplayed());
        holder.artist.setText(tempValue.getArtist());
        swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();
        view.setOnClickListener(new SongListOnItemClickListener(position));
        view.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
        holder.imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnPlayButtonClickListener(position));
    } else {
        TemporarySongViewHolder holder;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list_process_format, null);
        holder = new TemporarySongViewHolder();
        holder.artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artisttemp);
        holder.bar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ppbar);
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titletemp);
        holder.source = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sourcetemp);
        tempValue1 = (TemporarySongInfomation) data.get(position);
        String songName = tempValue1.getName();
        holder.source.setText(tempValue1.getVideoid());
        holder.title.setText(songName.length() > 45 ? songName.substring(0, 38) + "..." : songName);
        holder.artist.setText(tempValue1.getArtist());
        holder.bar.setMax(100);
        new UpdateProgressBar(holder.bar, tempValue1).execute();
// here is where the asynctask starts passing it the reference to progress bar!

    }

    return view;
}


private class UpdateProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    private TemporarySongInfomation songinfo;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    UpdateProgressBar(ProgressBar bar, TemporarySongInfomation tp) {
        progress = bar;
        songinfo = tp;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (!songinfo.isCompleted()) {
//this will be set to false when its done no problems here 
            publishProgress((int) songinfo.getProgress());
 // sending the message to onProgressUpdate
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        System.out.println("progress: "+values[0]);
// prints the values just fine!
        progress.setProgress(values[0]);
// setting the progressbar here!
    }
}
```

Also if I add a system.out.println(progress.getProgress()) after setting the progressbar via progress.setProgress() i always get 0

Comment: What exactly is not working? ProgressBar not shown?(if so, you forgot to call `progress.show()`)

Comment: it is showing as a circle

Comment: you need to call dismiss() on ProgressBar Instance when your task completes.

Comment: dismissing it is not why it isn't updating

Comment: what values you are getting in  System.out.println("progress: "+values[0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was looking for a horizontal progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Please add this method to your AsyncTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) 
{
     _yourProgressBar.dismiss();
}
```